# Dropdown menu close on mouseleave

Tags: javascript

I was read all similar thread here but no one work in my case.

So i need to modification on current code for open menu on hover, I need to close on mouseleave, not on click outsite the menu.

The code is

```
$( ".p-navEl:not(.is-selected)").mouseenter(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('data-has-children') && $(this).not('.is-menuOpen')){
    // has children
    $(this).find( ".p-navEl-splitTrigger[aria-expanded='false']:not(.is-menuOpen)" ).trigger( "click" );            
  } 
});
```

html

```
<div class="p-navEl" data-has-children="true">
  <a href="/users/" class="p-navEl-link p-navEl-link--splitMenu " data-nav-    id="users">Users</a>
  <a data-menu-pos-ref="< .p-navEl" class="p-navEl-splitTrigger is-menuOpen" role="button" tabindex="0" " aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="true"></a>
</div>
```

Suggestion how to fix that?

Comment: Please post also HTML code, because it may be relevant

Comment: What should happen on touchscreens?

Comment: @Greg-- I have another menu for mobile devices, this will work only on desktop.

Comment: @m.cichacz I added the html

Comment: @Dimitry I think it's still missing HTML for the menu itself. Please share all HTML that is related to question, or code that generates it.

Comment: @m.cichacz The problem is in javascript. HTML is ok. Because the menu is open and close (on click), I want to close when mouse leave from menu element.